# Format output in Hive Query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using a (simplified) query like this to get the status of my hive databases:

```
show databases; 
show tables
```

but it is a bit confusing because it runs all the lines together like this:

```
default
curtime_test
datetime_test
datettime_test
hivesampletable
sensor
sensor_part_subset
sensor_part_subset1
```

Is there anyway I can easily format the output, maybe add a header or something? I was hoping for something like this:

```
show databases
   default
show tables
   curtime_test
   datetime_test
   datettime_test
   hivesampletable
   sensor
   sensor_part_subset
   sensor_part_subset1
```

But this would be fine too:

```
---  show databases ---
default
---- show tables ---
curtime_test
datetime_test
datettime_test
hivesampletable
sensor
sensor_part_subset
sensor_part_subset1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below statement might add readability in your case.

```
select '------show databases----------';
show databases;
select '------show tables----------';
show tables;
```

Also use below statement to print header information.

```
set hive.cli.print.header=true;
show databases;
show tables;
```

Comment: The first suggestion seems to prints a line per row in that table, which makes it awkward unless you have a table lying around with exactly one row in it. Trying the second suggestion now.

Comment: The second adds a single unindented line - which helps a bit, but not a lot as your eyes have to seek it. Still hoping for something better.

Comment: Please present the output how you want it to be formatted.

Comment: In the first suggestion, try reducing the middle line to just 
`select '----------------';`

Answer (score 3):

I am 4 years late but this may help someone :)

**Option 1** - Use Beeline :  It nicely formats the table output and delimits with pipe character '|' . However, it also pads the data so if you are copy pasting into something like Excel, you will have to deal with space paddings.

**Option 2** - Redirect the output to a file : If you are running a script using `hive -S -f <file_name>` or `hive -e "select statement here"` then you can redirect the output to a file by using standard Unix redirection operator `>` . This needs some effort as you may have to convert tabs to pipes. E.g. the following command gives you pipe-delimited columns

```
hive -e "select first_name, last_name from employee_db.employee;" | sed -e 's/\t/|/g' > output_file.csv
```

**Option 3** - If you use Jupyter, then use PyHive and Pandas to show data within the notebook itself. Here is a [tutorial](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/97062/query-hive-using-python.html) about PyHive.